# R predict function: why it returns zero length prediction?

Tags: r, zero, predict

Update: I am using e1071 package for naiveBayes

I am new to R and trying to build Naive Bayes model around a toy data. Then I tried to call"predcit" on that model. The issue I saw is: the result from "predict()" has zero length. Please see the simple R repro code. Thanks for your inputs!

```
 df<-NULL

 df <- rbind(df, c(0,3))

 df <- rbind(df, c(1,1))

 df <- rbind(df, c(1,3))

 model <- naiveBayes(df[,2], df[,1])

 prediction <- predict(model, df[,-1])

 length(prediction)

 ## [1] 0
```

Comment: Which package are you using? `e1071`? I'm pretty sure your problem is you're not specifying a formula...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the dependent variable is expected to be a *factor*. Instead of using a matrix to store the data, I'll use a data frame (df below) which can store multiple variable types (e.g. numerics and factors). I store into df a factor Y, and a numeric X and run the model...

```
df<-data.frame(Y=factor(c(0,1,1)),X=c(3,1,3))
model<-naiveBayes(Y~X,df)
predict(model,df)
```

Alternatively, to show that it's the factor that fixed the problem (i.e. not the use of a formula)...

```
model<-naiveBayes(df[,2],df[,1])
predict(model,df)
```

Still works.

Comment: ...and in this case, having `df` as a data frame is better because data frames can hold multiple types of vectors (e.g. numeric, factor). If you were going to keep `df` as a matrix, you would have to split off the outcome column and then convert it to a factor.

Comment: @Marius I'll incorporate your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue arises from the fact that `naiveBayes` assumes that `y` is a categorical variable.

In your example data, there are no (obvious) categorical data or contigency table data.

If we take the example from the help, using `iris`, the fifth column is `Species` and is a factor variable.

```
library(e1071)
data(iris)
m <- naiveBayes(iris[,-5], iris[,5])
m
table(predict(m, iris), iris[,5])


            setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         47         3
  virginica       0          3        47
```

It works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how to make y as categorical variable?